# Docker port forwarding exposure

Tags: firewalls, port-forwarding, docker

I try docker with a simple webapp :

> docker run -d -v $(pwd):/app -p 8080:80 image_name

I have docker listen on 8080:

> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*
>   LISTEN      13304/docker

So I can test my web app through localhost:8080

I use iptables with UFW and I deny incoming except: 80, 443 and 22

But surprisingly, if I do a netcat from the Internet to my machine on port 8080 I can have access to my web app !!

Docker must do something special because if I start socat like this :

> socat TCP6-LISTEN:8080 TCP4:www.google.fr:80

I see :

> tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*
>   LISTEN      11577/socat

But this time I can't connect from the outside ... UFW do the his job ...

Answer (score 5):

Docker was just added his own iptables rules before UFW rules see https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/ for details.

to avoid the pb I put

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--ip 127.0.0.1"
```

in my /etc/default/docker. so I bind only to localhost and it's not reachable from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Binding to localhost breaks internal routing for me.   I use

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"
```

to fix this problem.